# Locally scoped variable is not defined in function

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a function `currentPlayer` as follows:

```
function currentPlayer(players) {
  return players.findIndex(player => player.current) || 0;
}
```

I am trying to use this function in a reducer as follows:

```
export function players(players = [], action) {
  players = players.slice();
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case DELETE_PLAYER:
      const currentPlayer = currentPlayer(players);
      if (currentPlayer === action.index) {
        players = switchNextPlayer(players, currentPlayer);
      }
      players.splice(action.index, 1);

  }
  return players;
}
```

On running this code, I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: currentPlayer is not defined

The code works if I change the variable name as follows:

```
const currentPlayerIndex = currentPlayer(players);
```

I thought that the variable `currentPlayer` would be scoped in the reducer function. What is going on here?

Comment: `const currentPlayer = currentPlayer(players);` note 3 names in line

Comment: The function is being overshadowed by the new `currentPlayer` binding which hasn't been initialized by the time you evaluate it, so you end up with a reference error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` declaration is interpreted *before* the initialization expression. Thus your local scope gets its own `currentPlayer` symbol first, and then the initialization expression is evaluated. In the initialization expression, therefore, `currentPlayer` refers to that newly-declared local symbol, not the function.

Comment: i.e if it was `let` instead of `const` the above expression would be broken into: `let currentPlayer; currentPlayer = currentPlayer(players);`